# Avoid null value when fetching comments

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Help please!

I am using getx to manage flutter app state.

This is the controller:

```
class CommentsController extends GetxController {
  final postModel = Rxn<PostModel>();
  RxList<CommentModel> comments = <CommentModel>[].obs;

  static const int _limit = 19;

  //Setter method to update postModel
  void setPostModel(PostModel post) {
    postModel.value = post;
  }

  Future<void> onRefresh() async {
    _lastDocumentSnapshot = null;
    ended.value = false;
    await fetchAllComments();
  }

  Future<void> fetchAllComments() async {

    late QuerySnapshot res;
    final comment = <CommentModel>[];

    try {
      res = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collectionGroup('postComments')
          .where('status', isEqualTo: CommentStatus.verified)
          .where('postID', isEqualTo: postModel.value!.postID)
          .orderBy('date_uploaded', descending: true)
          .limit(_limit)
          .get();
    }
}
```

This is the view:

```
class CommentsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/commentspage';

  const CommentsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Obx(
      () {
        PostModel post = Get.arguments;
        final controller = Get.put<CommentsController>(CommentsController());
        controller.setPostModel(post);

        return Scaffold(
//remaining code
}
```

The problem is when the user lands on the view, the post value is still null, so the query to fetch comments returns an error: Null checker used on null value, only by refreshing the page does it get a value and run the query. I suspect that it may be due to postModel not being observable in the controller. I need to make there is no null checker entirely because on the comments page, a post is sure to be not to be null.

Comment: Use a FutureBuilder https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html?v=1.0.19&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5tLFjOqBgQMVb0NBAh0q9AvXEAAYASAAEgJVlfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `postModel`'s state, inside `Obx`.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  PostModel post = Get.arguments;
  final controller = Get.put<CommentsController>(CommentsController());
  controller.setPostModel(post);

  return Obx(() {
    if (controller.postModel.value == null) {
      return const SizeBox(); // or widget related to loading.
    }
    return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
  });
};
```